# Increasing RAM and CPU in VMWare vCloud Director

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Hi I have privilleges of "Organizational Administrator" in my company's private dev cloud. I tried to add a custom VM by selecting a VM in the organization's public catalog and tried to increase its RAM. How ever after the changes are made the VM does not start. It only starts when I reduce the RAM . How can I increase this limit ??

Comment: It might help if you add the VM host version, the OS version, just in general some more specifics.

Comment: Sorry i only have access to the vcd web interface. Anyway our cloud dev env host hundreds of vms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the fault was not checking the vCPU and Memory hot add options. 
It starts fine after checking the options

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the resource allocation policy for your dev environment (Organization VDC). If the RAM is overcommitted or there's a hard limit on the resource pool, coupled with HA *“Disallow power on VMs that violate availability constraints”*, you'll need to contact the administrator. This could also be something wrong with the VM template,

but it's likely a resource issue. Can you provide the actual error message?

Comment: acutally message is a simple VM could not start message no details

Comment: Can you check with someone who has an administrative view of the environment?